# Xcode 7.2 quits unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios9.2

I am trying to open the lower version of Xcode and suddenly my Xcode got crash and now whenever I am opening any of the Xcode version, I am getting this error that says " Xcode quit Unexpectedly " with three options: Ignore, Report & Reopen but still none of the option is working.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. This looks like a bug from the IDE, I would suggest filling a bug request to Apple here: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code / project. try it after restarting your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scratching my brain for last 24hrs, finally I found a solution to it. 
We can open Xcode from Command prompt with these line of codes:

```
1.  cd /
2.  sudo ls
3.  cd Applications
4.  sudo ls
5.  cd Xcode.app
6.  cd Contents/MacOS
7.  ls
8.  ./Xcode
9.  sudo ./Xcode
```